# Getting ID of element created by javascript/ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a page where I used ajax to get all the images in a directory and appended it to the body. Also in this ajax call, I assigned an ID for each image created.

However, when I view the page source in my browser, the HTML for the images does not appear. This creates a problem where I can't get these image elements by their ID because the HTML code is not loaded with the page. When trying to use document.getElementById("one of the images ID"), I get a TypeError indicating that that var is null.

Is there a way to get these elements individually? If not, is there a better way to create these images where I can access the their  properties and attributes?

EDIT:

This is my ajax call to get the images and append it to a div.

```
var imgDir = "/items_img";
var extension = [".jpg", ".png"];

$.ajax({
    url:imgDir,
    success:function(resp){
        $(resp).find("a:contains(" + extension[0] + "), a:contains(" + extension[1] + ")").each(function(){
            var sliced = this.href.substring(this.href.lastIndexOf("/"));
            var idName = sliced.slice(1,-4);

            $("#items").append("<img id='" + idName + "' class='items_icon' src='" + imgDir + sliced + "'>");
        });
    }
});
```

Then in another external js file I have this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var newImg = document.createElement("img");

    var itemDiv = document.getElementById("items_div");

    var abyssalScepter = document.getElementById("Abyssal_Scepter");

    abyssalScepter.onclick = function(){
        var iconDiv = document.createElement("div");
        iconDiv.className = "icon_div";
        itemDiv.appendChild(iconDiv);
        newImg.src = "/items_img/" + abyssalScepter.id + ".png";
        iconDiv.appendChild(newImg);
    }
});
```

console logging idName shows that I have the right ID, yet variable abyssalScepter is null. Also inspecting the live DOM shows all the img HTML with their properties and attributes.

Comment: also post your code? for actual problem.

Comment: Use a live DOM debugger like Firebug (Firefox) or the developer console (Chrome). `view source` doesn't display changes made by JS. `document.getElementById` will work fine assuming the ID is correct. Post your code though so others can help you with a more complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem should be with the Async function to get the images, in your code the process that will look for the images should happen after and only after you create the image from your Ajax call, because if you execute it before the Ajax call those images does not exists. so you could do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url:imgDir,
    success:function(resp){
        $(resp).find("a:contains(" + extension[0] + "), a:contains(" + extension[1] + ")").each(function(){
            var sliced = this.href.substring(this.href.lastIndexOf("/"));
            var idName = sliced.slice(1,-4);

            var img = $("#items").append("<img id='" + idName + "' class='items_icon' src='" + imgDir + sliced + "'>")
            img.click(function(){ handleClick(img) });
        });
    }
});
```

HandleClick is the function with the logic that you need to execute.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but this would limit the capability of assigning different functions to each img. I solved my problem though. Luckily, the design of my website involves a tab that shows a div where the images are appended to. So when I created an onclick function to the tab to load the external js file.

Unfortunately, my solution does not work for every design, so answers are still welcomed. Looking at the "network" in firefox "inspect", I can see that the external js file is loaded before all the images are created, which is the reason of the null TypeError.

Comment: Well, your question was about the error with the function, I just give you a solution to your question, now apart of that I see you have a design problem that is totally different of what this question is about. I think the best that you could do is create a new question with more details about your problem, the full problem, because we both agree that your problem in this question is resolve.